# Is it possible to create named functions in Python similar to C macro?

Tags: python, function, macros

Sorry for the confusing title.

I would like to do the following: (Similar to `defstruct` in Lisp)

```
def mkstruct(structname, field_dict):
    # create a function called "structname" and get/set functions
    # called "structname_get(s, field_name)" and "structname_set(s, field_name, value)"

# Create a struct "lstnode"
mkstruct("lstnode", {ndkey : 0, nxt: None})
# Make a new struct
node = lstnode()
node_set(node, "ndkey", 5)
v = node_get(node, "ndkey") # v should be 5
```

This can be done in C with a macro define. The reason I am not using a class is because The "struct" I am creating will be "tied" to a database (just a text file in some format in this case). And I don't want to take up any memory associated with an object - I will represent the struct as a number (an object ID if you will)

Comment: So what do you want these getters and setters to do if there's no actual memory?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your aversion to classes? If you put your functions in a dictionary, you have essentially just reinvented the class. It sounds like that's where this is heading.

Comment: I have a giant tree structure. If I can get away with using an OID instead of an object, then I am not using any object references as a result. Every object access is translated to a database operation (lookup and update) instead.

Comment: Have you found that object references are bad in some way? If the amount of memory overhead added by using an object instead of a loose assortment of functions is significant, you may want to reconsider your decision to use Python.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a step in the direction of what you want:

```
def mkstruct(name, attrs):
    def init(self):
        self.id = # not sure how you want to get the id

    def getattr(self, attr):
        if attr not in attrs:
            raise AttributeError(attr)
        # put your database lookup statement here

    def setattr(self, attr, value):
        if attr not in attrs:
            raise AttributeError(attr)
        # put your database update statement here

    return type(
        name,
        (object,),
        __init__=init,
        __getattr__=getattr,
        __setattr__=setattr)

lstnode = mkstruct("lstnode", ("ndkey", "nxt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that what you're looking for is already provided by the `type` built-in:

```
def mkstruct(structname, field_dict):
    return type(structname, (object,), field_dict)

lstnode = mkstruct("lstnode", {'ndkey' : 0, 'nxt': None})
node = lstnode()
node.ndkey = 5
v = node.ndkey
```

If you need just the keys in `field_dict` to be members of the structure, you can add `'__slots__'` to `field_dict`.

Note: This doesn't implement any setter or getter, but as pointed out already by the comments, this is not really needed when using classes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that this isn't easy to do in python - after some research. The only way to add a inner function to the global namespace is to modify the globals() dict, which is rather awkward.

```
>>> def mkfunc(funcname):
...   def func():
...     print "my name is %s" % funcname
...   func.__name__ = funcname
...   return func
... 
>>> mkfunc("abc")
<function abc at 0xb773ae64>
>>> globals()["abc"] = mkfunc("abc")
>>> abc()
my name is abc
```

As for my own problem, I am content to do the following:

```
def mkstruct(fields):
    def maker(args):
        # validate @args against @fields
        oid = db_insert_row(fields)
        return oid
    def getter(oid, fieldname):
        rec = db_retrieve(oid)
        return rec[fieldname]
    def setter(oid, fieldname, value):
        db_update(oid, fieldname, value)
    return (maker, getter, setter,)

lstnode, lstnode_get, lstnode_set = mkstruct({nodekey: 0, nxt: None})
n = lstnode(nodekey=5)
```